# Mathematical joke regarding three people leaving a house

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

I don't get this mathematical joke - can someone explain?

> From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_joke):
>
> A physicist, a biologist and a mathematician are sitting in a street café watching people entering and leaving the house on the other side of the street. First they see two people entering the house. Time passes. After a while they notice three people leaving the house. The physicist says, "The measurement wasn't accurate." The biologist says, "They must have reproduced." The mathematician says, "If one more person enters the house then it will be empty.

Comment: What part don't you get exactly?

Comment: Heh.  Heh.  Negative people counted in a house.  Add one more and... now it's empty :-/

Comment: This is one of my favorite jokes. But when I tell it, I always mention that the three are watching an initially empty house. This explains why they all feel the need to comment on the situation.

Comment: Wiki has a page on math jokes.... there is something beautiful about that.

Comment: @Jorik It's also my favourite, but I tell it with an elevator instead of a house. The pro side is that it can actually start empty and produce the observations mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the joke ! I did not know this one. :-)

Comment: I usually tell it "*the physicist notes that there is a flux of 2.5 people per hour through the house, with an experimental error on the order of 0.5 people*".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question

Comment: @LaurentDuval It used to be (arguably) a question because of the title.  The latest edit removed it.

Comment: @Beska I've edited the question so that it appears like one.

Comment: @LaurentDuval Oh come on, now. This is a fine and fun question that could honestly help give the OP a little insight into how math works.

Comment: Ok, at the time of reading, or I might be blind, this was not a question

Comment: The variant I heard was: _after lecturing to two people, sees three come out behind – considerably disturbed – sees one go back in – “Thank goodness lecture theatre empty now!”_

Comment: @Jorik So then who was correct? It couldn't have been the mathematician because you can't have a negative number of people.  It couldn't have been the biologist because not enough time had passed (it says three *people* left the house, not two people and a baby who would not be able to leave under their own power as well as other obvious lack of clues that this would be possible).  That leaves only the physicist, which suggests the unlikely but apparently only remaining possibility that they all failed at such a simple counting task!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Note that there are $2$ people who enter the house at first. Then $3$ people leave the house.

The joke probably lies in the fact that the mathematician **assumes that there were initially no people inside the house** (The others do too), and so then there are:
$$2-3=-1\text{ people}$$
In the house at the moment. Therefore, if one person enters the house, the amount of people in the house is:
$$-1+1=0 \text{ people}$$
Thus, the house will be empty.

Comment: Facepalm! ... It's so simple, I'm mightily embarrassed I didn't get it straight away

Answer (score 38):

I think the point of the punchline is that the mathematician simply solves the math problem as observed, and appears totally unconcerned with the impossibility of having -1 people in a house in the real world.

Sciences like physics and biology are about explaining the real world, but in mathematics explaining the real world is not a requirement.

Comment: Probably the best answer because it actually explains why the joke is funny and not just why what the mathematician says might be considered factually correct.

Comment: @BallpointBen - Well, this *is* a math site, so you might expect people to just solve the math problem and ignore the real world aspects :)

Answer (score 27):

From my understanding, it's just a take on stereotypes of physicists, biologists, and mathematicians.  Physicists are generally concerned with real-world measurements, and may often attribute issues to experimental error (counting the wrong number of people here).  Biologists end up attributing the extra person due to sex (reproduction).  The mathematician sees $2-3=-1$ people in the house, so if one more person enters, there will be $-1+1=0$ people.

Answer (score 7):

input = 2 
output = 3 
so, the system contains 2-3= -1 people.
So he says if another person enters the house would have -1 + 1 = 0 people :)